# How do I sign out of Thunderbird on my Mac?

Tags: mac, email, thunderbird

I have the Thunderbird mail client on my mac, and when I go into the application it automatically opens my mailbox.  I'm going to be using a shared computer soon and would like to be able to 'sign out' of Thunderbird but I can't for the life of me see how to do this?

On forums / other sites it says do 'Tools > Options > Security > Passwords'

These options aren't available on the mac version.

Any help would be awesome.

Emily,

Answer (score 0):

**There is no "Sign-out" button**

I assume that this shared computer will also have a shared user account. In the case of separate user accounts, there would be no issue (each person's Thunderbird would open to their configuration)

**Solution: Forget the password -**

> Menu > Tools > Options > Passwords > Saved Passwords > Delete entry in question

Then you will be prompted to input your password every time you wish to check for new mail.

Sources: [No Sign-out](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1002733), [Remove Saved Password](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1142451)